# the error is "Unexpected beginning of statement

Tags: sql-server

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE (
    employeeID int PRIMARY KEY,
    FNAME TEXT NOT NULL,
    LNAME TEXT NOT NULL,
    ,BID int
)

CREATE TABLE branches (
   branchID int PRIMARY KEY,location TEXT NOT NULL,
   OpeningTimes TIME NOT NULL,mgrID int,
   vendorID int,FOREIGN KEY(mgrID)
        REFERENCES EMPLOYEE(employeeID)
);

ALTER TABLE EMPLOYEE 
   ADD FOREIGN KEY(BID) 
      REFERENCES branches(branchID)
```

The error is:

> Unexpected beginning of statement. branchID

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please tag your RDBMS as SQL varies among the product (Oracle, Postgres, SQL Server, etc.). And no SQL is not short for SQL Server. Consider also line breaking your SQL statements.

Comment: seems to be working here https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bdMGgXb3rgDbo195oQWBGa/0 assuming you are using mysql which I'm guessing from the error message.

Comment: You seem to be separating just one of your three statements with a semi-colon. Which statement is causing the error?

Comment: `FNAME TEXT NOT NULL` NO NO NO NO NO - this sql server datatype has been deprecated for almost two decades and should not be used.

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra comma in the first CREATE TABLE statement before "BID"